UICalendarView が意図した通り再描画されない
カレンダーの特定の日をタップして、右上の＋ボタンを押すと、ハーフモーダルが出現して、カレンダーの特定の日付の予定を記述して、その予定を、ハーフモーダルが下がった時に、カレンダーに青丸が反映されるようにしたいのですが、UICalendarViewが再描画されません。どのようにすれば再描画して、カレンダーに表示されるようになりますか?
.sheet(isPresented: $isModalPresented, onDismiss: {
            fetchEvents()
}) {
            CalendarRegisterScreen(selectedDate: $selectedDate, calendarRegisterType: .constant(.register), event: nil)
}

全体のコード
import SwiftUI
    import SwiftData
    import SwiftDate
    
    struct CalendarScreen: View {
        @State private var selectedDate: String = Date().toFormat("yyyy年M月d日")
        @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
        @State private var fetchItems: [Event] = []
        @State private var isModalPresented = false
        @State private var isEditorPresented = false
        @State private var selectedEvent: Event?
        @State private var eventDates: [Date] = []  // イベント日付リスト
    
        var isModalAndEventSelected: Bool {
            isEditorPresented && selectedEvent != nil
        }
    
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TopView(selectedDate: $selectedDate, isModalPresented: $isModalPresented)
                CalendarView(selectedDate: $selectedDate, eventDates: $eventDates)
                    .background(.white)
                DateView(selectedDate: $selectedDate)
                List {
                    ForEach(fetchItems, id: \.self) { event in
                        EventListView(event: event)
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedEvent = event
                                isEditorPresented = true
                            }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteEvent(at:))
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
            .onAppear {
                fetchEvents()
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedDate) {
                fetchEvents()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>(
                get: { isModalAndEventSelected },
                set: { isEditorPresented = $0 }
            ), onDismiss: {
                fetchEvents()
            }) {
                CalendarRegisterScreen(selectedDate: $selectedDate, calendarRegisterType: .constant(.editor), event: selectedEvent)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isModalPresented, onDismiss: {
    // このタイミングで、カレンダーの再描画を行なって、カレンダーに青丸が追記されるようにしたいのですが、されないです。
                fetchEvents()
            }) {
                CalendarRegisterScreen(selectedDate: $selectedDate, calendarRegisterType: .constant(.register), event: nil)
            }
        }
    
        // イベントの削除処理
        private func deleteEvent(at offsets: IndexSet) {
            for index in offsets {
                let eventToDelete = fetchItems[index]
                // データベースから削除
                modelContext.delete(eventToDelete)
            }
    
            do {
                // データベースを保存して削除を確定
                try modelContext.save()
                // イベントを再取得してリストを更新
                fetchEvents()
            } catch {
                print("データの削除中にエラーが発生しました: \(error)")
            }
        }
    
        private func fetchEvents() {
            do {
                let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Event>()
                let fetchedEvents = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
    
                fetchItems = fetchedEvents.filter { event in
                    let selectedDateAsDate = selectedDate.toDate(format: "yyyy年M月d日")
                    return event.eventDate.isSameDay(as: selectedDateAsDate!)
                }
    
                eventDates = fetchedEvents.map { $0.eventDate }
                print("eventDates: \(eventDates)")
                
            } catch {
                print("データの取得中にエラーが発生しました: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
struct TopView: View {
    @Binding var selectedDate: String
    @Binding var isModalPresented: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                isModalPresented = true
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")  
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 16)
        }
        .padding(.trailing)
    }
}

struct DateView: View {
    @Binding var selectedDate: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(selectedDate)
                .padding()
                .font(.title2)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct EventListView: View {
    var event: Event

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(event.startTime.toFormat("HH:mm"))
                Spacer()
                Text(event.endTime.toFormat("HH:mm"))
            }


            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(event.title)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(event.place)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 16)

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
}

下記のコードがCalendarViewのコードになります。
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI
    import SwiftDate
    
    struct CalendarView: UIViewRepresentable {    
        @Binding var selectedDate: String
        @Binding var eventDates: [Date]
    
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }
    
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
            let view = UICalendarView()
            let selection = UICalendarSelectionSingleDate(delegate: context.coordinator)
            view.selectionBehavior = selection
            view.delegate = context.coordinator
            view.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
            return view
        }
    
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
            print("updateUIView が呼ばれました: eventDates = \(eventDates)")
            context.coordinator.updateEventDates(eventDates)
            uiView.setNeedsDisplay()
            uiView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    
        class Coordinator: NSObject, UICalendarViewDelegate, UICalendarSelectionSingleDateDelegate {
            private let parent: CalendarView
            private var markedDates: [DateComponents] = []
    
            init(_ parent: CalendarView) {
                self.parent = parent
            }
    
            // イベントの日付を更新してカレンダーにマークをつける
            func updateEventDates(_ dates: [Date]) {
                markedDates = dates.map { date in
                    Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
                }
            }
    
            func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
                // 現在のカレンダーの日付とマークされるべき日付を比較してマークをつける
                if markedDates.contains(where: { markedDate in
                    markedDate.year == dateComponents.year &&
                    markedDate.month == dateComponents.month &&
                    markedDate.day == dateComponents.day
                }) {
                    return .default(color: .blue, size: .small)  // 青丸を表示
                }
                return nil
            }
    
            func dateSelection(_ selection: UICalendarSelectionSingleDate, didSelectDate dateComponents: DateComponents?) {
                guard let dateComponents = dateComponents,
                      let year = dateComponents.year,
                      let month = dateComponents.month,
                      let day = dateComponents.day else { return }
                parent.selectedDate = "\(year)年\(month)月\(day)日"
            }
        }
    }

